# EF Core many-to-many configuration - how to pass it to UsingEntity()

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to place all configuration of `JoinEntity` to `JoinEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<JoinEnitity>`.

The problem is  - how to provide it for `UsingEntity()` call? EF Core has the `UsingEntity(Action<EntityTypeBuilder> configureJoinEntityType)` interface, and maybe I could call `.UsingEntity(b => new JoinEntityConfiguration().Configure(b))`.

But `b` here is `EntityTypeBuilder`, and `Configure()` wants specific class - `EntityTypeBuilder<JoinEntity>`. Can I somehow cast `EntityTypeBuilder` to `EntityTypeBuilder<JoinEntity>`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

I have a many-to-many relationship:

```cs
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

From here I create a join entity:

```cs
public class BlogTag
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public required Blog Blog { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public required Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

From here I create an EntityConfiguration for each of these three classes:

```cs
public class BlogConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Blog>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Blog> builder)
    {
        builder
            .ToTable("Blogs");

        builder
            .HasMany(blog => blog.Tags)
            .WithMany(tag => tag.Blogs)
            .UsingEntity<BlogTag>();
    }
}
public class TagConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Tag>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Tag> builder)
    {
        builder
            .ToTable("Tags");

        builder
            .HasMany(tag => tag.Blogs)
            .WithMany(blog => blog.Tags)
            .UsingEntity<BlogTag>();
    }
}
public class BlogTagConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<BlogTag>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BlogTag> builder)
    {
        builder
            .ToTable("BlogTags");

        builder
            .HasKey(blogTag => new {
                blogTag.BlogId,
                blogTag.TagId
            });

        builder
            .HasOne(blogTag => blogTag.Tag)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(blogTag => blogTag.TagId);

        builder
            .HasOne(blogTag => blogTag.Blog)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(blogTag => blogTag.BlogId);
    }
}
```

Finally, in my DbContext.OnModelCreating:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .ApplyConfiguration<Blog>(new BlogConfiguration())
        .ApplyConfiguration<Tag>(new TagConfiguration())
        .ApplyConfiguration<BlogTag>(new BlogTagConfiguration());
}
```